# ASP.NET @Html.Action's parameter's value gets overridden

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET and I am stuck with `@Html.Action`. I'd appreciate some help and explanation please.

I have a parent view which corresponds to a user form built on basis of a student model. I would like the student's avatar to be rendered within the parent view with a partial view.

To do so I am using an `@Html.Action` that calls a controller different from the parent's one and I pass it the student image id like this :

```
<div id="avatarStudent">
    @Html.Action("DisplayImg", "Img", new { imgId = Model.ImgId, })
</div>
```

That `DisplayImg` method in the `Img` controller is charged to retrieve the image thanks to the `Model.ImgId` parameter and send the data to a partial view with an `Img` model :

```
public ActionResult DisplayImg(int id)
{
    ImgService imgService = new ImgService();
    Img img = new Img();
    img = imgService.Get(id).ToModelImg();
    return PartialView("_Img", img);
}
```

On debug that parameter value of the `@Html.Action` corresponds to the actual image id of the student. That's fine !

BUT that value changes for the student id once passed to the `Img` controller.

It seems that its taking that value from the URL of the parent view and overriding the value of the parameter with it.

Though at this stage the form hasn't been submitted yet.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: change `public ActionResult DisplayImg(int id)` to `public ActionResult DisplayImg(int imgId )` and try

Comment: Gosh you are right ! Thanks Nijin..

Comment: I didn't think respecting the name of the parameter counted for the binding in that case.. thanks again